# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in React project

Tags: reactjs

I tried running a react app and it gives the following error:

```
yarn run v1.19.1
$ react-scripts start
C:\Users\Rahul\yantra-front\yantraksh-app\node_modules\ajv-errors\index.js:1
```

index.js:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rahul\yantra-front\yantraksh-app\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I am a beginner in React. How can I solve this?

App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';
import Main from "./main";

import './scss/App.scss';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';
// import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';

import {ToastContainer} from "react-toastify";


export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        // window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Main/>
                </Router>
                <ToastContainer />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I have updated App.js as well as index.js for easy understanding.

I opened this in pycharm and it says

> ESLint: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Try in some other IDE on your system as Pycharm is for python and for react you require JSX code to be compiled in JS.

Comment: @KrinaSoni It says the same in terminal also when i try to yarn start

Comment: Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rahul\yantra-front\yantraksh-app\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:12:16 did you validate or debug the code here?

Answer (score 0):

I been has this error in create-react-app version 3.4.1, node v12.19.0, npx 6.14.8 and yarn 1.22.5.

This error consist in terser-webpack-plugin folder, it is with ajv files corrupted. Solved with a copy and paste.

Copy:

```
`node_modules\ajv\lib`
```

To:

```
`node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\ajv\`
```

Error before this copy:

```
> react-scripts start

\workspace\Documents\Test\front\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\ajv\lib\ajv.js:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\workspace\Documents\Test\front\node_modules\terser-webpack-
plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:15:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
```

In open js files from `terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\ajv`, editor can't open the file type.